# How do I include an og excerpt for a blog post using jekyll?

Tags: facebook, jekyll

Do you know how to pass a post's excerpt to facebook when sharing a link?

I have a jekyll blog and when people want to share a post they get this:

[link to img](http://cl.ly/image/0e3O032B0O2h)

Example of a link I'm trying to share:

[link](http://www.taigeair.com/My-Biggest-Problem-with-Siri-on-iOS-7/)

Thanks

Comment: `when people want to share a post they get this`- anything wrong with that?

Comment: yes I'd like the summary to pull from the post, not from the main website. thx

Comment: Add the code you are using for sharing

Comment: I don't understand. The sharer just takes the post url and posts it in the fb status update box.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add some cutomised text you should instead use **[Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog)**.

You can use the direct URL to invoke feed dialog:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
 app_id={app-id}
 &display=popup
 &caption={caption}
 &link={link-to-share}
 &description={description}
 &redirect_uri={redirect-url-to-your-site}
```

Check all available parameters [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog#params)